# User Input from Ruby on Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedly

Im trying to grab the users input value (:url) in my rails app. I believe its

```
params[:user_input]
```

but i dont know how to implement it into my controller. Do I place it anywhere or in a specific method?

**Method**

```
 def index
 @posts = Post.all

 embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => '', :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
 url = params[:user_input]
 @obj = embedly_api.extract :url => :user_input
end
```

how can I get the user_input url so I can pass it into the hash???

Comment: Give your params o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` hash contains a mapping of the names of your HTML form controls to their values provided by the user. You access each one with `params[key_name]`.

In your case, I think you want to create a local variable out of `params[:url]`. That's fine. But then you use it like this.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => '', :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
  url = params[:url]
  @obj = embedly_api.extract :url => url
end
```

However, the local variable isn't necessary, so you could make the code slightly more succinct by removing the local variable and doing this instead:

`@obj = embedly_api.extract :url => params[:url]`

Answer (score 2):

you should change your code to:

```
def index
   @posts = Post.all

   embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => '', :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0      (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
   @obj = embedly_api.extract :url => params[:user_input]
end
```